# Experience Editor Ignores Workflows

Tags: experience-editor, publishing, workflow

I recently followed this great tutorial to implement workflows on our site:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFDUgiQCTmU&list=PLfRWjEN_vCUZqAk8ks5j36yM-BCWup-SZ&index=1

Everything is set up and works well with changes made in the Content Editor.

However any changes made via the Experience Editor do not register in the Workflow. Whether that be changing text in a component (even ones which alter the core fields), or adding removing components. The notification at the top of the page remains:

> The item is in the 'Approved' workflow state in the 'Content Workflow'
>   workflow.

Whereas I would expect it to change to 'draft' state when anything is added / removed / changed.

Any ideas on how I can force the Experience Editor to be included in a workflow would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you please share how does your workflow commands looks like?

Comment: Are you logged in as an admin or a regular user? Admin users bypass all workflow requirements.

Comment: Remember that on the Experience Editor, you might be seeing multiple content items and may not be editing the current item.  That "approved" is only for the current item that you're on and not for the other related content that are associated through component's datasources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be changed to Draft state if you created a new version of the item. Please avoid using your admin access as it will allow you to update the same version of an item.

By using content authoring access, User will be forced to create a new version.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that, because Experience Editor runs in the context of the site you are looking at, the site definition in config requires the attribute **enableWorkflow="true"**.

```
<site name="mySite" enableWorkflow="true" ... />
```

This fixed the issue for me. Hope this helps.

Abbie